# GDB no such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, debugging, assembly, gdb

I'm following these lessons from [OpenSecurityTraining](http://opensecuritytraining.info/IntroX86-64.html).

I've reached the lab part where I've to train myself on a CMU Bomb. They provide a x86_64 compiled CMU Bomb that you can find here to train on : [CMU Bomb x86-64](http://opensecuritytraining.info/IntroX86-64_files/bomb-x64.zip) originally from a 32-bit bomb from [CMU Labs for
Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective (CS:APP) 1st edition](http://web.archive.org/web/20150219073026/http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/public/1e/labs.html).

I had a virtualized 64 bits Elementary OS distribution where I disassembled the CMU Bomb without problems using GDB. Now, I've a 64 bits Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (not virtualized) and when I try to reproduce why I did on my Elementary OS, I get the famous error.

I run these commands :

```
gdb ./bomb-x64
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400dbd: file bomb.c, line 37. -- why bomb.c ?
(gdb) r
...
bomb.c: no such file or directory
```

**Edit :** I can create breakpoints on others functions of the CMU Bomb and it works as expected.
Example :

```
(gdb) b phase_1
Breakpoint 3 at 0x400f00
(gdb) r

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000400f00 in phase_1 ()
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function phase_1:
=> 0x0000000000400f00 <+0>: sub    $0x8,%rsp
   0x0000000000400f04 <+4>: mov    $0x4023b0,%esi
   0x0000000000400f09 <+9>: callq  0x401308 <strings_not_equal>
   0x0000000000400f0e <+14>:    test   %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000400f10 <+16>:    je     0x400f17 <phase_1+23>
   0x0000000000400f12 <+18>:    callq  0x40140a <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000400f17 <+23>:    add    $0x8,%rsp
   0x0000000000400f1b <+27>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

I've heard of ia32-libs but this doesn't do anything more since I'm on 64bits Ubuntu and run a 64bits compiled CMU Bomb, am I wrong ?

Comment: It appears your bomb.c file is not in gdb's source path. You'll need to use the "directory" command. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/21928876/10077.

Comment: When the error happens, what happens if you type `disas` or, failing that, `next`?

Comment: @FredLarson I don't have sources. This is the point of this lab/exercise. It's on purpose. However, I can add breakpoints on others functions and it works as expected. Only the break main refers to the source file.

Comment: @Tony I'll try this as soon as I'm at home.

Comment: I downloaded it and ran it under gdb on 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04. Aside from periodic complaints `bomb.c: No such file or directory`, it runs normally. After `b main` and `run`, I get `Starting program: /var/tmp/bomb-x64`, `Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe088) at bomb.c:37`, `37 bomb.c: No such file or directory.`, and `(gdb)`. Typing `c` allows it to proceed normally to the Welcome message. Are you seeing something different?

Answer (score 20):

Use dir command to set source path

```
dir /usr/src/debug
```

in above path. Your code should present.

Comment: You should elaborate .

Comment: Does it search recursively?

Answer (score 9):

The executable contains debugging symbols, which indicate the file (and particular line in the file) corresponding to each bit of assembled code.  This is what allows you to step through C code in the debugger.  The debugging symbols are put there by the compiler (e.g. by using the `-g` argument to gcc).

If you don't have the C files that were used to compile the executable, the debugger won't be able to show you the C, and you'll be limited to looking at assembly.

Comment: I do want to look at assembly but I can't since the breakpoint main is referring to a source file I don't have. I would like to remind you that I'm issuing this error on my Ubuntu only. I don't have this error on my (virtualized) Elementary OS.

Answer (score 0):

```
(gdb) list 
/home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/freertos/tasks.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) set substitute-path /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/ C:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v4.4/
```