# GDB list shows nothing

Tags: gdb

A program compiled with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -g3 main.c .

$ gdb a.out

$ l

$ main.c: No such file or directory.

It is unable to display program lines with line number. let me know If i am missing something ?

However I am able to run program , with run command even backtrace I am able to get.

My issue is same as [gdb can not load source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928876/gdb-can-not-load-source-file)
but , GDB version 7.8.

Comment: It is *unlikely* that you've shown us what you *actually* see (the prompt is wrong for one thing). When asking questions, it helps to be precise: details *matter*.

Comment: thanks for your advice, I can add details , what I suppose is someone who is aware of GDB will be able to understand with above mentioned details.

Comment: "someone who is aware" -- I am *very* aware, and I can *guess* what's happening, but I wouldn't. Clearly you can't be bothered to supply correct details, so why show I be bothered to try to help you?

Answer (score 0):

GDB needs source code to be present on same machine as in where binary been run.
mine was cross compilation , I was running program on different host . That's why I had that issue.